# Connecting Android Devices over WiFi

Tags: android, android-wifi

**What I'm trying to do:** Connect a family of android devices on a WiFi network. The family is private and immutable, so no other android devices on the network can talk to the family, and the devices in the family will never change. This is a custom app designed specifically for the devices in the family, and will not be distributed via app store or any other mediums.

**My Issue:** I have a mandatory singleton class to manage all WiFi communications on one device that will do most of the "talking", but seeing as most examples for WifiP2pManager are done on the activity level I am having a difficult time getting things working.

**What I'm looking for:** A checklist of mandatory steps, minus implementation, to explain how to use WifiP2pManager properly. Implementation must be disregarded because that is the primary source of my confusion. However, if I can get the steps fully decoupled from real world use, I can understand what I need to do much better.

Also, I am curious if there are any other alternatives for WiFi communications that may be a little more straightforward or be more appropriate for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use AllJoyn framework... 

 here is link: https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/run-sample-apps/basic/android

Comment: I'm on windows 7, and its taken me quite some time to find any substantial guides for setting alljoyn up. Any way I can build the android source on my machine?